# MySQL/PHP, getting all the data in one go

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database with three tables:

```
Products
MaterialsProducts
Materials
```

The relationship between the tables are like this:

```
Materials 1-* MaterialsProducts *-1 Products
```

Quite often I need to retrieve **200+ products** and their related material data (from the `Materials` table).

Currently it is done like this:

```
SQL: select all relevant products
PHP: iterate through the selected products, calling the database to select 
     material data for each product(generating a database call for each product!)
```

Is there a way to select all relevant products + their material data at the same time? And still have each product only take up one row in the result.

So the solution shouldn't be `"SELECT * FROM products p, materialsproducts mp, materials m WHERE p.id = mp.productid AND m.id = mp.materialid WHERE x"`. (That SELECT would make each product take up more than one row in the result.)

Comment: do you want one row per product where each product composition is collapsed into a single row?

Comment: That's exactly what I want. One row per product, with materialdata collapsed into 1+ fields in the same row.

Comment: did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `left join` to get all data you need

**documentation** [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html)

Your query have a mistake

```
"SELECT * FROM `products` p LEFT JOIN `materialsproducts` mp on p.`id` = mp.`productid` LEFT JOIN `materials` m ON m.`id` = mp.`materialid` WHERE $whateveryouneed"
```

remember to not limit your `WHERE` to only 1 `ID` otherwise you will need more queries.

`UPDATED`
as asked

`products has a 1-* relationship with both materialsproducts and typesproducts. materialsproducts has a *-1 relationship with materials. typesproducts has a *-1 relationship with types.`

So you can make a `left join` query as above in this way

```
SELECT * FROM `products` p
LEFT JOIN `materialsproducts` mp
ON p.`id` = mp.`productid` 
LEFT JOIN `materials` m
ON mp.`mp_field_id_here` = m.`m_field_id_here`  //here you need to change with actual field to compare
LEFT JOIN `typesproducts` tp
ON p.`id` = tp.`tp_field_id_here`  //here you need to change with actual field to compare
LEFT JOIN `types` t
ON tp.`tp_field_id_here` = t.`t_field_id_here`  //here you need to change with actual field to compare
```

then you can add a `where` statment to limit result to something that suits you

```
WHERE WHATEVER_YOU_NEED
```

`UPDATED AGAIN`

to limit result to only some filed just change `*` to something specific as

```
"SELECT p.`Product_Name`, m.`Material_1`, m.`Material_2, m.`Material_3`, t.`Type_1`, t.`Type_2` FROM .....
```

**NOTE** I assume you retrieve `material 1, material 2, material 3` from `material` table wich is why i used as prefix `m`. Either way i used as prefix `t` for `type 1 and type 2` because i thought they are fileds of `type` table, otherwise you can change them according to your needs.

Comment: What if I have two more tables to work with, so the database scheme looks like this: 
materials 1-* materialsproducts *-1 products
types 1-* typesproducts *-1 products

How would the SQL look then? Would I need to make a UNION? (i.e. your query for materials UNION your query for types)

Thanks,
Louisa

Comment: i didn't understand what is the schema please add in the question. Also i already think you can still using another `left join`. What is the correlate field wich correlate typesproducts to typesproducts and typesproducts to products?

Comment: products has a 1-* relationship with both materialsproducts and typesproducts.

materialsproducts has a *-1 relationship with materials.

typesproducts has a *-1 relationship with types.

Comment: It works, but we could save some processing if it returned:
`Product Name; Material 1|Material 2|Material 3; Type 1|Type 2`

Instead of:
`Product Name; Material 1; Type 1
Product Name; Material 2; Type 1
Product Name; Material 3; Type 1
Product Name; Material 1; Type 2
Product Name; Material 2; Type 2
Product Name; Material 3; Type 2`

Anyone know if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT p.*, mp.*,m.* 
FROM products p 
JOIN materials m ON p.id=m.prd_id 
JOIN materialsproducts mp ON m.mp_id=mp.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that query doesn't put all the data on one row per product.

Answer (score 0):

It is not simple to have a query like this compress the materials data into a single row for each product - so I don't think that plan will work well for you.

What I would recommend instead is to use a normal JOIN query (much like the one you put in your question and rejected), then use PHP code to deal with the cases where a single product has multiple rows in the result set because it is linked to multiple materials.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to combine materials related to the same product into a single list while grouping by products:

```sql
SELECT
  p.ProductID,
  p.ProductName,
  GROUP_CONCAT(m.MaterialName) AS Materials
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN MaterialsProducts mp ON p.ProductID  = mp.ProductID
INNER JOIN Materials          m ON m.MaterialID = mp.MaterialID
GROUP BY
  p.ProductID,
  p.ProductName
;
```